# CKEditor5 v. 10.1.6 stopped showing up in Drupal10 site

Tags: drupal, ckeditor, text-editor, ckeditor4.x, drupal-10

Some time between before-Thanksgiving and Monday morning, the CKEditor on one of my sites stopped working. I am running CKEditor5 10.1.6 on Drupal 10.1.6. Without CKEditor, the HTML in my body fields is displaying as plain text instead of being hidden behind the "source" option.

[how fields are displaying without CKEditor working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XkZq.png)

[how fields should display with CKEditor (from another D10 site)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u35Qg.png)

I have verfied that the CKEditor module is installed & enabled. I've tried downgrading to a previous version of Drupal 10. I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the CKEditor module, flushing all caches, and checking the Permissions. None of this has restored the CKEditor toolbar for this site.